# Find folder without specific subfolder

Tags: ubuntu, find, command-line-interface, directory

I am looking for a way to go through a set of folders in a unix terminal and list the folders that don't have a certain subfolder.

So, say I have 5 folders, each containing subfolders with numbers 1-5, 2 folders don't have the subfolder number 2 and I want to find the names of those folders.

Clear what I mean? Any ideas anyone???

Comment: so you want to output the name of the of the folders that doesn't have a particular name?

Comment: I think you can find the folders that you are looking for and take a negation of it

Comment: @KevinRed No, I want the name of the folders that do not have a subfolder with a particular name.

Comment: so you want the name of the root folder such that the sub folders inside it doesn't have a particular name.right??

Comment: I want the names of the folders that do not have a subfolder with a particular name.